# Android Emulator simply will not load

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am using Android Studio on a Ubuntu virtual machine.

I not yet got to the point where I am debugging my code.  I am only trying to launch the emulator in Android Studio. After learned that  my computer could not handle a high resolution emulators, I picked the appropriate ARM image. But when I launched the device from teh Device Manager, I could see that it seemed the emulator was trying to load but it stopped after just a few seconds with this error.
[image]

Logcat is, of coure empty.  I have not even gotten to the point where I am debugging code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows OS and when I get this error, I open the task manager, find the qemu-system-x86_64.exe process and kill it.

[image]

You can do something like this in Ubuntu.